# How to determine infra needs for a spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

I am looking for some suggestions or resources on how to size-up servers for a spark cluster. We have enterprise requirements that force us to use on-prem servers only so I can't try the task on a public cloud (and even if I used fake data for PoC I would still need to buy the physical hardware later). The org also doesn't have a shared distributed compute env that I could use/I wasn't able to get good internal guidance on what to buy. I'd like to have some idea on what we need before I talk to a vendor who would try to up-sell me.

**Our workload**

We currently have a data preparation task that is very parallel. We implement it in python/pandas/sklearn + multiprocessing package on a set of servers with 40 skylake cores/80 threads and ~500GB RAM. We're able to complete the task in about 5 days by manually running this task over 3 servers (each one working on a separate part of the dataset). The tasks are CPU bounded (100% utilization on all threads) and usually the memory usage is low-ish (in the 100-200 GB range). Everything is scalable to a few thousand parallel processes, and some subtasks are even more paralellizable. A single chunk of data is in 10-60GB range (different keys can have very different sizes, a single chunk of data has multiple things that can be done to it in parallel). All of this parallelism is currently very manual and clearly should be done using a real distributed approach. **Ideally we would like to complete this task in under 12 hours.**

**Potential of using existing servers**

The servers we use for this processing workload are often used on individual basis. They each have dual V100 and do (single node, multigpu) GPU accelerated training for a big portion of their workload. They are operated bare metal/no vm. We don't want to lose this ability to use the servers on individual basis.

Looking for typical spark requirements they also have the issue of (1) only 1GB ethernet connection/switches between them (2) their SSDs are configured into a giant 11TB RAID 10 and we probably don't want to change how the file system looks like when the servers are used on individual basis.

Is there a software solution that could transform our servers into a cluster and back on demand or do we need to reformat everything into some underlying hadoop cluster (or something else)?

**Potential of buying new servers**

With the target of completing the workload in 12 hours, how do we go about selecting the correct number of nodes/node size?

For compute nodes

- How do we choose number of nodes
- CPU/RAM/storage?
- Networking between nodes (our DC provides 1GB switches but we can buy custom)?
- Other considerations?

For storage nodes

- Are they the same as compute nodes?
- If not how do we choose what is appropriate (our raw dataset is actually small, <1TB)
- We extensively utilize a NAS as a shared storage between the servers, are there special consideration on how this needs to work with a cluster?

I'd also like to understand how I can scale up/down these numbers while still being able to viably complete the parallel processing workload. This way I can get a range of quotes => generate a budget proposal for 2021 => buy servers ~Q1.